# How do I limit the results of the command find in bash?

Tags: bash, find

The following command:

```
find . -name "file2015-0*" -exec mv {} .. \;
```

Affects about 1500 results. One by one they move a previous level.

If I would that the results not exceeds for example in 400? How could I?

Comment: If there are 1500 results, which 400 should it choose? Even with a deterministic way (e.g. alphabetical) it would be difficult to guess which files might be returned or not.  You should explain more broadly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Fedorqui, thank you for your reply!

Comment: Hi Fedorqui, thank you for your reply!
It doesn't matter the order, only has about 400 results at a tiime.
The idea is to move 400 files because another process running in the previous level decreases its perfomance.
I mean, for that example will be glorious moves in four parts: 1st of 400, 2nd of 400, 3rd of 400 and 4th of 300.
BR!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 find . -name "file2015-0*" | head -400 | xargs -I filename mv  filename ..
```

If you want to simulate what it does use `echo`:

```
 find . -name "file2015-0*" | head -400 | xargs -I filename echo mv  filename ..
```

Comment: Excellent!
Thank you so much Tiago!

Comment: Glad it helped! please accept the answer if you think that's the best one.

Comment: Yes! I will accept it!
Really, I was looking for a parameter of "find" to stop it when the 400 results found ok (like crtl C but working alone :) ).
That way could be applied to a great amount more than 1500 and the access to disk will not be intensive.
Anyway, today for 1500 its really fine!
BR
Mariano

Comment: Not sure this is helpful for anyone but myself, but I had to put the `| head -400` bit _after_ the `xargs` command. In my case I was just calling `ls` from xargs. This post got me on the right track tho!

Comment: If you get unexpected results (missing lines), ensure that you are not using `xargs -n` option (with n≠1).

Answer (score 2):

You can for example provide the `find` output into a `while read` loop and keep track with a counter:

```
counter=1
while IFS= read -r file
do
   [ "$counter" -ge 400 ] && exit
   mv "$file" ..
   ((counter++))
done < <(find . -name "file2015-0*")
```

Note this can lead to problems if the file name contains new lines... which is quite unlikely. Also, note the `mv` command is now moving to the upper level. If you want it to be related to the path of the dir, some bash conversion can make it.