# limit number of results of find, head is not working

Tags: bash, find, limit

What can be the other thing besides head to limit my find command's result to only 50? 
`find -L $line | head 50 | -exec ls {} > $a$(basename $line) \;`

The above thing is not working. I want to limit my output as it is taking long time to do task and decreasing performance of my computer. :<

Comment: `head -n50` instead of `head 50`. Or you missed it only here in the question?

Comment: @ViktorKhilin i missed that in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use `xargs` instead of `exec`?

Check it, works good.
`find / -type f | head -n5 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 ls`

Your case:
`find -L $line | head -n50 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 ls > $a$(basename $line)`

Comment: sir, what is the difference between `xargs` and `exec` ?

Comment: Shortly: `xargs` constructs an argument list from the output of the find command and passes it to `ls`. `exec` executes the command `ls` on each individual file. In your task I've chosen `xargs` just because know the solution with it, and I'm too lazy to find the right syntax for `exec` :) Xargs or exec, you will have the same result.

Comment: :-) Thanks @Viktor

Comment: Can you show me `$line` variable?

Comment: `find` will find all the files by the pattern, if you want it to stop finding after N founded files, you can try the second solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413735/how-do-i-limit-the-results-of-the-command-find-in-bash?noredirect=1&lq=1 but it's looks like bad solution as for me.

Comment: So that means, this will not take as much time as much it takes to find all results right? That means head 50 really works are stops find after find gets 50 results? this is important for me to know. Please clarify me. @Pesa

Comment: @Pompy Taking everything back, sorry! Kernel will actually terminate `find` after `head` gets all the data it needs. See this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243350/why-does-using-yes-on-bash-pipelines-not-cause-infinite-loops/243352#243352) and another related [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84813/what-makes-a-unix-process-die-with-broken-pipe). Both explain this behavior in further detail.

Comment: Thanks @PesaThe :-)

Answer (score 1):

To handle filenames with `<newline>`, it's best to use a null delimiter:

```
find -L "$line" -print0 | head -z -n 50 | xargs -0 ls > "$a$(basename "$line")"
```